# Is there a way to remove all namespaced binds in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, jquery-events

I have some simple code like:

```
$('#modal-buttons [href*=close]').bind('click.modalClose',function(){
  app().modal('close')
});
```

But let's say I wont know everywhere the `click.modalClose` will be bound, is there a way to destroy all of those specific binds no matter what the element rather than having to do the following?

```
$('#modal-buttons [href*=close],.someOtherelement,#onemore,.another').unbind('click.modalClose');
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of *all* bindings, just do:

```
$('*').unbind('click.modalClose');
```

That'll get all of them.  Alternatively, you could make sure that the binding always happens via your own API, and then you can keep track of what elements are actually affected.  (If you're going to unbind the handlers from all elements they're bound to, however, I don't see the point, unless your page is of epic proportions and the `$('*')` thing takes too long.)

Comment: No, i just wanted to find a nice DRY solution, and i thought about `$('*')` but thought it might be sorta a heavy task, but then again, it's just unbinding events no animations or anything.

Comment: Well the browsers all (even antique ones) support `getElementsByTagName("*")`, so the real worry should probably be a function of your page sizes. If they're not super huge, the unbinding probably won't take a noticeable amount of time.